# Yii custom inheritance implementation

Tags: oop, yii, abstract-class, customization

I want to have an abstract class (**Report**) (which is located in protected/components) and subclasses that extend **Report**. These classes don't have a particular table (MySQL). These classes represent different kind of reports with different fields to show in the word-report.

Is it possible to do this in Yii? Is there something especial should I declare within these classes?

I want to do something like this:

```
In protected/components:
abstract class Report {
    private $name;

    public function __construct( $name ) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

Then in protected/models:
class Proposal extends Report {
    private $contract_date;

    public function __construct($name, $contract_date) {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->contract_date = $contract_date;
    }
}

When I try to instantiate Proposal:
$report = new Proposal(3, 4);

I got this error:
2011/12/14 13:37:21 [error] [php] include(Proposal.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory (/var/www/yii-1.1/framework/YiiBase.php:421)
```

Any pointers/help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you mean [helper class](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/165/understanding-autoloading-helper-classes-and-helper-functions/).
It should be all right as long as you do import right in Yii

Answer (score 0):

Try put Proposal.php which contain your Proposal class in protected/components

Comment: I haven't done this but I was trying to avoid it because I consider my Proposal.php being a model. I still wonder what is the best approach to do this in Yii.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code in your main config file:

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
),
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a good example of what you need
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/198/single-table-inheritance/